# Model 'changing', but it's not

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a view:

```
class FancyView extends Backbone.View
    template: #fancytemplate

    initialize: () ->
        @add()
        @model.bind('change', @update)

    add: () ->
        $(@el).html($(@template).tmpl(@model.toJSON())).prependTo('#fancy')

    update: () ->
        $(@el).html($(@template).tmpl(@model.toJSON()))
```

When a change comes in logging `@model.changedAttributes()` in update shows changes under `data` but logging `@model` still shows the old data and thus nothing changes on update.

Why is `@model` still the old data?

Comment: Not sure this can be debugged without seeing the model code, and maybe sample output for the logging you describe.

Comment: Sorry fixed it, that whole 'shows changes under data' was because it was putting it in a `data` sub model!

Comment: So... is the question still valid?

Comment: nrabinowitz No I figured it out, thank you.

Comment: If you have figured it out, just post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see more... what does the template look like?  What templating engine are you using?

I can say that I see one problem off the bat... you need to use the "fat arrow" (`=>`) instead of (`->`) for your `update` function.  If you don't, `@el`, `@template` and `@model` will be in the wrong context when the event fires.

```
update: =>
    $(@el).html($(@template).tmpl(@model.toJSON()))
```

Comment: Sorry! Just fixed it, that whole 'shows changes under data' was because it was putting it in a data sub model!